# Is it possible to output a variable with zero value as blank in Fortran?

Tags: variables, fortran, output

I would like to output real variables in a formatted file. If the variables are non-zero, format statements are used. But if variables are zero, then only blank spaces are outputted, similar to what Iw.0 does. Is it possible to do this in the format statements? Thank you.

Comment: i'm no fortran expert, but I think you may need to check the variables you are interested in via an IF statement, and if they are equal to zero then do your WRITE command having that specific FORMAT statement to do what you wish.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. That will be too complicated, since I have many variables.

Answer (score 5):

No, not with a format statement, but this is reasonably easy to do by writing the values to a string and processing.  Below is a demo.  Probably better to put into a subroutine.

```
program demo

   real, dimension (6) :: values = [ 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 6.0 ]
   character (len=100) :: string
   integer :: pos

   write (string,'( 6 (1X, F4.1 ) )' )  values
   write (55, '(A)' )  trim (string)

   MakeBlanks: do

      pos = index (string, "0.0")

      if ( pos < 1 )  exit MakeBlanks

      string (pos:pos+2) = "   "

   end do MakeBlanks

   write (55, '(A)' )  trim (string)

end program demo
```

Comment: Thanks, M. S. B. I was able to use your approach to do what I wanted to. Keep in mind that Index(string, " 0.0") can only find the first " 0.0" in the string.

Comment: Yes, re index finding the first "0.0".  That why the demo shows index used in a loop that replaces the first "0.0" found, checks for another, etc., then exits when there are no more.

Comment: Your demo is brilliant. I did not realize that the preceding “0.0” has already been replaced with blanks. So I had to use something like string(i:j) to process “0.0” at different locations in the string.