# Output is '*' when writing a real to a string

Tags: fortran

I have a real `CURRENTTIME` I want to convert to a string named `TIMEDIR`. As `TIMEDIR` has to change size it is allocatable. As far as I could find out, the allocation works fine. Also, I checked that `CURRENTTIME` has a value.

```
ALLOCATE(CHARACTER(LEN=1)::TIMEDIR)
WRITE(TIMEDIR, '(F1.0)') CURRENTTIME
```

But

```
WRITE(*,*) TIMEDIR
```

outputs `*`, where it should be `0` (`CURRENTTIME` is 0.0000000). I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure that TIMEDIR has a value ?

Comment: yes it has the value "*" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing the output as a floating point number. Floating point numbers always have a decimal point or an exponent to differentiate them from integers. Thus the narrowest output of a float possible is 0., i.e. 2 characters, and a format of F1.0 will always result in a "*" being printed as the field width is insufficient for what is being written.

Comment: <some integer> = INT(<some real>)

Answer (score 2):

[Ian Bush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41571825) says what you need to know: output for a real value using the `F` edit descriptor requires a field width of at least 2.  I'll elaborate a bit on some other aspects.

You mention

> As `TIMEDIR` has to change size it is allocatable

but in the code fragment we see

```
WRITE(TIMEDIR, '(F1.0)') CURRENTTIME
```

This suggests a little misunderstanding.  [It may be that there's no confusion, but I'll labour the point for the benefit of any other reader coming to the question.]

When an output format looks like `Fw.d` for `w` greater than zero the width of the output field is *always* `w`.  This "always" means: whatever the value of the corresponding variable, the effect of the `write` statement above on `TIMEDIR` is to have a single character non-blank.

Now, as in that other answer, 2 is the minimum field width for output of a real value<sup>[1]</sup>.  As with all other numeric output formatting, if the field isn't wide enough for the corresponding value the field consists entirely of `*`s.  `F1.0` will always result in output `*`.  If you want output `0.` (or `0,`)<sup>[2]</sup> you'll need `F2.0`.

Coming back to the "varying size of `TIMEDIR`", output format `F2.0` is (possibly) sufficient for non-negative values of `CURRENTTIME` less than 10, but for negative values or values not less than 10 it isn't.  It may well be that this is where `F0.d` comes in.  It's only with this form of the `F` edit descriptor that the width of the field depends on the output value.  That's probably an answer to another question, though.

Finally, as you mention

> I have to find out how to make "0" out of "0."

I'll point out that you're looking at having to do some additional logic, such as [mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39819102/).

---

<sup>1</sup> And 2 may not be sufficient, even for a zero value: `print '(SP,F2.0)', 0.`

<sup>2</sup> The choice of `0.` and `0,` depends on the decimal mode: `print '(DC,F2.0,DP,F2.0)', 0., 0.`

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. What does F0.d print, though?
As CURRENTTIME is between 0 and 3 seconds, I didn't have to worry about the value becoming greater than 10.

Comment: `F0.d` behaves much like `Fw.d` but instead of a width of `w` the field is the smallest width that isn't lots of `*`s.  So, no leading/trailing blanks but with `d` fractional digits.